# Использование переменной в sql запросе Delphi 7

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-7

На главной форме создаю строковую переменную `s`. присваиваю ее значение `edit`-у на сторонней форме, все прекрасно присваивается, однако если подключить запрос `sql`, то при запуске приложения это переменная оказывается `null`, где моя ошибка?

присваиваю и отправляю на форму

```
s := ADOQuery2.Fields.Fields[0].AsString;    
form4.Edit4.text := s;
```

при этом без запросов все работает.
при открытии нужной формы, хочу использовать значение этого `edit`-a

```
ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('a').Value := strToInt(edit3.Text);
ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

вот здесь программа обнаруживает `null`, как мне это обойти?

Comment: Есть глобальная переменная, в ней я храню код сотрудника при аутентификации. Сотрудники совершают продажи на форме 4. при добавлении продажи автоматически записывается код сотрудника в таблицу продажи, так вот, эта переменная почему то пустая (так говорит программа при запуске)

Comment: Какая связь между `Edit4` и `edit3`?

Comment: Перепутал немного, извините, и там и там эдит 3. но суть не в этом

Comment: Фраза "при открытии нужной формы" имеет смысл только для Вас. Люди, находящиеся от Вас за сотни и тысячи километров, не могут заглянуть к Вам в мозг. Используйте термины среды Delphi и код, если хотите, чтобы Вас поняли.

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял, то высылаю вам пример кода

Форма№1

```
unit Unit1;
interface
uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Data.DB, Data.Win.ADODB,Unit2;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ADOQuery1: TADOQuery;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    ADOQuery1ID: TFMTBCDField;            
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  form2: TForm2;
  S: string;
begin
  ADOQuery1.Open;
  S :=  ADOQuery1.FieldByName('ID').AsString;
  Edit1.Text := S;

  form2 := TForm2.Create(Self);
  form2.Edit1.Text := S;
  form2.ShowModal;
end;

end.
```

Форма№2

```
unit Unit2;
interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Data.DB, Data.Win.ADODB,
  Vcl.Grids, Vcl.DBGrids;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    ADOQuery1: TADOQuery;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('A').Value := Edit1.Text;
  ADOQuery1.Open;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый очевидный ответ - Edit3 еще (уже) не создан в тот момент, когда вы его присваивает. Или еще не инициализирован. Без кода ничего другого ответить не выйдет.

Comment: Не является ответом